# How to set custom <h1> for categories in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm newbie in wordpress and wondering how can I set custom `<h1>` for categories in wordpress. At the moment: `<h1>Category:Category name</h1>`. I've spent half day to find out how to do that. Advices from articles don't work.

Plugins: Yoast SEO, All-in-one SEO pack, WP SEO Meta
Editing `functions.php` in theme folder

```
add_action("category_edit_form_fields", 'mayak_category_meta');
function mayak_category_meta( $term ) {
    ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label>Заголовок (title)</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mayak[title]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'title', 1 ) ) ?>"><br />
                <p class="description">Не более 60 знаков, включая пробелы</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label>Заголовок h1</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mayak[h1]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'h1', 1 ) ) ?>"><br />
                <p class="description">Заголовок страницы</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label>Ключевые слова</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mayak[keywords]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'keywords', 1 ) ) ?>"><br />
                <p class="description">Ключевые слова (keywords)</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}

function mayak_save_meta( $term_id ) {
    if ( ! isset($_POST['mayak']) )
        return;
    $mayak = array_map('trim', $_POST['mayak']);
    foreach( $mayak as $key => $value ){
        if( empty($value) ){
            delete_term_meta( $term_id, $key );
            continue;
        }
        update_term_meta( $term_id, $key, $value );
    }
    return $term_id;
}
add_action("create_category", 'mayak_save_meta');
add_action("edited_category", 'mayak_save_meta');

function mayak_filter_single_cat_title($term_name) {
    $terms = get_category( get_query_var('cat'));
    $cat_id = $terms->cat_ID;
    $term_name = get_term_meta ($cat_id, 'title', true);
    return $term_name; 
}
add_filter('single_cat_title', 'mayak_filter_single_cat_title', 10, 1 );

function mayak_single_cat_title ($term_name){
    if(empty($term_name)){
        $terms = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ));
        $cat_id = $terms->cat_ID;
        $term_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
    }
    return $term_name;
}
add_filter( 'single_cat_title', 'mayak_single_cat_title', 10, 1 );

function mayak_cat_caption($caption) {
    $terms = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ));
    $cat_id = $terms->cat_ID;
    $caption = get_cat_name($cat_id);
    echo $caption;
}

function mayak_cat_h1($name_cat) {
    $terms = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ));
    $cat_id = $terms->cat_ID;
    $name_cat = get_term_meta ( $cat_id, 'h1', true );
    echo $name_cat;
    if(empty($name_cat)){
       echo mayak_cat_caption($caption);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are trying to modify and the result that you are trying to get? The question does not really make sense, man. Please try to be as clear as possible and provide your code and examples.

Comment: I've just edited my question and added code that I added to functions.php . After that I got <h1>Category:Title value</h1> instead of <h1>h1 value</h1>

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to edit archive.php file in theme folder and adding this code:

```
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_h1 = get_field('h1', $term);
if ( empty( $term_h1 ) ) 
    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
else 
    echo '<h1 class="page-title">' . $term_h1 . '</h1>';
the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
?>
```